# Python - Calling Linux command from Thread Pool not working

Tags: python, linux, multithreading, threadpool

--Hi guys, --

I have about 4000 (1-50MB) files to sort.

I was thinking to have Python call the Linux sort command.  And since I'm thinking this might be somewhat I/O bound, I would use the threading library.

So here's what I have but I when I run it and watch the system monitor I don't see 25 sort tasks pop up.  It seems to be running one at a time?  What am I doing wrong?

```
...
print "starting sort"
def sort_unique(file_path):
    """Run linux sort -ug on a file"""
    out = commands.getoutput('sort -ug -o "%s" "%s"' % (file_path, file_path))
    assert not out

pool = ThreadPool(25)
for fn in os.listdir(target_dir):
    fp = os.path.join(target_dir,fn)
    pool.add_task(sort_unique, fp)

pool.wait_completion()
```

[Here's where ThreadPool comes from](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/577187/), perhaps that is broken?

Answer (score 1):

You're doing everything correct.

There is something which is called [**GIL**](http://docs.python.org/c-api/init.html#threads) in python;
Global Interpreter Lock - which eventually cause python to execute only one thread at time.

Choose subprocess instead :), python is not multithreaded.

Comment: I know about the GIL, but I think the GIL should be released when the Linux command is running, right?

Comment: I wouldn't say so, but I would like to hear confirmation from someone else as well.

Comment: I agree with bua, use subprocess.

Answer (score 0):

Actually this does seem to be working.  I spoke too soon.  I'm not sure if you guys want to delete this or what?  Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

Normally people do this by spawning multiple processes. The `multiprocessing` module makes this easy to do.

On the other hand, Python is pretty good at sorting, so why not just read the file into a list of strings `file.readlines()` and then sort it in Python. You would have to write a `key` function to use with `list.sort()` to do the `-g` option, and you would also have to remove duplicates, i.e. `-u` option. The easiest way (and a fast way) to remove duplicates is to do `list(set(UNsortedfile))` before you do the sort.